# What does an asterisk on top of a set mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm reading an article which defines something called a hash function.

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $H:\{0,1\}^*\to\{0,1\}^n:m\to h=H(m)$...

I know that $\{0,1\}^n$ is the cartesian product of the set with itself $n$ times, but I am not familiar with the meaning of the asterisk in this context for $\{0,1\}^*$

Is anyone familiar with the notation?

Comment: I think this is [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star).

Comment: It should be emphasized that the answer given here (the Kleene star) applies to *this particular case*, as easily inferred from the context. There are dozens, if not hundreds, of different uses of a superscript asterisk in mathematics (and whatever text you're reading is not doing a very good job if the notation has not been clearly introduced and occasionally recalled).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case $$\{0,1\}^*=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty\{0,1\}^n$$

In context of hash-functions, $\{0,1\}^*$ would be the set of strings with "letters" 0,1; including the empty string but no single infinite string.